# In-active accounts

Tags: feature-request

Currently there are millions of users in StackExchange network. But many of the accounts can be seen as inactive. Many users have asked the questions and just left the network. Many of them maybe spam/fake accounts.

It goes this way. A person creates account, asks a couple of questions and leaves. Other users may answer the question, or may represent some doubts related to question, but there is no OP available now. So, those questions are completely inactive and no further discussion occurs. This seems to be quite a waste of resources and time.

Here, I would like to suggest that there should be some reputation/privilege after which user can ask question. This can prevent many spams. A couple of  techniques are as follows:

- User must be a member for at least five to seven days then some badge may be awarded and user can ask questions there after. Visiting the site for some number of consecutive days can also be useful.
- Just like commenting privilege, let the new user answer on some question. After, lets say a reputation score of 5/10, the user is allowed to ask question.

Comment: 1: Trivial for a spammer to separate setup and exploitation of an account by some days. 2: Apparently, that leads to many more crap answers. 3: Why make their posts read-only? And what does killing the account, as long as posts remain, buy us anyway?

Comment: Actually, I myself have caught a couple of people in my neighbourhood who just create an account, ask something and vanish. Yes, there can be crap answers, but if those answers are not up-voted, then there would be no reputation change on that account resulting in no change of privilege. Killing an account is not a better option that I realize. I've edited post for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no requirement that people who ask questions stay around, participate, or accept answers. You seem to not quite get the goal of SO (actually, the entirety of Stack Exchange), which is to *create a collection of knowledge*. That the knowledge comes about by a person posting a single question and getting an answer and then not returning again is irrelevant; the knowledge is still there for others in the future.

Setting up barriers to entry is not an approach to anything. We *want* people to ask questions here. They need to be asked in accordance with our quality standards and within the topic guidelines that have been established, but we *encourage* people to ask questions that have not been asked before on the site. When someone asks a question here, it's because they have a problem that needs a solution; forcing them to wait several days to ask is counter-productive, both in regards to meeting this site's goals and in finding the user a solution to that problem that can benefit others in the future.

Put yourself in that user's position: you've got a problem for which you need to find a solution, you've worked for hours (or days) trying to solve it, you've searched everything you can on Google (or Bing, or whatever you prefer), and as a last resort you turn to SO, only to find that you have to create your account and then wait several days before you're allowed to ask your question. Does that seem reasonable? Or productive? It certainly doesn't seem like a way to encourage people to participate. *You have a problem? OK. Create an account, and then come back in a week and we'll let you ask for help then. Oh, and by the way, we want you to spend time with us in the future sharing any knowledge you may have to benefit others (if, of course, they survive the waiting period).*

And as far as inactive accounts: it doesn't cost you to leave those accounts here; there's no impact on you because they exist. Inactive accounts are deleted automatically by the system when certain conditions exist, but whether they remain or not shouldn't concern you. It may be an issue for the people who maintain the databases at SE, but unless you're one of them it's not something with which anyone needs to be concerned.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understood the real intent. It's all about knowledge sharing. Thanks for making this clear.